# Foundation 6 accordion active item creates page layout error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zurb-foundation, accordion

I'm using a Foundation 6 accordion as a central element on a page, and I'd like it to load with the first accordion item open, which is possible with the "is-active" state class. But on the initial load, the open item pushes the rest of the accordion over my footer, which remains stationary. You can see what I mean on this [test page](http://cruciall.ist/list/c831e18a-15ac-4486-8bd6-2ba0171ecf8e.html). The same thing happens when I use one of the accordion deep links in the right sidebar. The footer moves to its correct position if you resize the browser or click on another accordion item. I've tried placing scripts in different places in the body to change when the active item loads, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

set the accordions parent height to auto

```
height:auto
```

whats happening is with the fixed height the accordion overflows its parent. So for example on the sample link you gave the parent would be the div with the class large-6 columns

```
.large-6 columns {height:auto;}
```

fixed the problem

Comment: That didn't work for me, but maybe I misunderstand. I added the height:auto language to this line: 


`<div class="large-6 columns"  style="height: auto; background-color:#A0AEB5;" data-equalizer-watch>` 


and I still get the same result.

Comment: actually upon further investigation it appears the js for your accordion is firing after your dom elements load. Trying moving your scripts to the head of your html so they're executed before your footer

Comment: That does solve the accordion spacing problem, but creates a whole 'nother set of issues with grid spacing:  http://cruciall.ist/list/scriptsinheader.html

Comment: make sure jQuery script is before Foundation for sites 6

Comment: That takes me back to the original problem. Seems like the solution is to have the accordion script in the header, with the rest of the Foundation script at the end of the body.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the data-equalizer on that row was apparently fixing the height of the column with the accordion prior to activating the accordion pane. When I removed the data-equalizer-watch from that column everything rendered properly.